# error on interface result: is not assignable to type

Tags: typescript

Hello i'm trying to create an interface to get the following return in typescript:

```
  {
    "field": "departament_name",
    "errors": [
      "constraint": "O nome do departamento precisa ser do tipo String",
    ]   },
```

but I'm not getting it I'm getting the following error when I try to add the object to my array:

> Type 'string []' is not assignable to type 'constraints []'.   Type
> 'string' is not assignable to type 'constraints'.ts (2322)

interface:

```
export interface constraints {
  constraint: string
}
export interface errorFormater {
  field: string;
  errors: constraints[]
}
```

function:

```
export const formatErrors = (validationErrors: ValidationError[]): errorFormater[] => {
  let response: errorFormater[] = [];
  for (let error of validationErrors) {
    let field: string = error.property;
    let constraints: string[] = [];
    for (let constraint in error.constraints) {
      if (!error.constraints.hasOwnProperty(constraint)) {
        continue;
      }
      constraints.push(error.constraints[constraint]);
    };
    // console.log(property, errorMessage)
    response.push({ field, errors: constraints });
  }

  return response;
}
```

Comment: `let constraints: string[]` not the same as `errors: constraints[]` when you try push `response.push({ field, errors: constraints });`

Comment: if `errors` is an array of object, should contain braces {} else, `:` is not allowed in array of strings. is your sample data correct?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ValidationError.constraints` type is not matching `Constraint` type. If `ValidationError` is your own type, you will have to either use the same `Constraint` type like this:

```
export interface IConstraint {
  constraint : string;
}
export interface IErrorFormater {
  field: string;;
  errors: IConstraint[];
}
export interface IValidationError {
  constraints : IConstraint[];
}
```

Or you could make a type cast (please don't..) https://techformist.com/type-casting-typescript/

Answer (score 0):

You should change your constraints varaible type
from:

```
let constraints: string[] = [];
```

to:

```
let constraints: constraints[] = [];
```

And your response push to:

```
constraints.push({ constraint: error.constraints[constraint] });
```

This should work and you will get the response you want.

Cheers,